# JSHint with rails asset pipeline requires

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, jshint

When running jshint to validate JS code, I often get errors like

```
line 264, col 11, 'Cookies' is not defined.
```

Cookies come from

```
//= require js.cookie
```

Which compiled as part of Rails asset pipeline, so JSHint doens't know about it.

Is there a way to set this up so that JSHint runs on a file with all dependencies in place? Or are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [globals](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#globals) option to make jshint aware of shared globals.

If the above proves to be too tedious, then you run jshint after running the files through sprockets - ie. run `rake assets:precompile` and then run jshint on generated files in `public/assets`.

But the best course of action I can recommend is something different:

You should consider using a proper module system as opposed to using sprockets for javascript dependency management. This will alleviate the root problem of shared globals (which is a widely regarded poor programming practice).

While the community had come up [multiple module systems](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) with varied levels of community acceptance - the best option right now is to embrace the [ES6 modules standard](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html). It is good to finally have a standardized approach for modularity. I have recently written a short [guide](http://lorefnon.me/2015/11/15/a-minimal-setup-for-using-es6-modules-in-rails.html) on integrating ES6 modules with rails.

In a nutshell, the ES6 modules standard is a superior option for organizing javascript today as opposed to solutions like AMD, CommonJS or Sprockets directives which were developed in an era when no standardized solution for modular javascript was available.